# How to Fix this java code?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, maven

I have this code:

```
package org.DX_57.osgi.SH_27.impl;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import java.util.Properties;
import org.DX_57.osgi.SH_27.api.SessionHandle;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.framework.Constants;
import org.osgi.framework.Filter;
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceReference;
import org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker;


public class SessionHandleApp implements BundleActivator {

    public static final String DSNAME = "jdbc/Oracle";
    public ServiceTracker st;

    @Override
    public void start(final BundleContext bc) throws Exception {
        debug("Activator started");


        Filter filter = bc.createFilter("(&" + "(" + Constants.OBJECTCLASS
                + "=" + DataSource.class.getName() + ")" + "(jndi-name="
                + DSNAME + ")" + ")");
        st = new ServiceTracker(bc, filter, null) {

            @Override
            public Object addingService(ServiceReference reference) {
                DataSource ds = (DataSource) bc.getService(reference);
                try {
                    debug(ds.getConnection().toString());

                SessionHandle sh = new SessionHandleImpl();
                                sh.ds = ds;
                                bc.registerService(SessionHandle.class.getName(), sh, new Properties());

                } catch (SQLException e) {
                }

                return super.addingService(reference);
            }

            @Override
            public void removedService(ServiceReference reference,
                    Object service) {
                super.removedService(reference, service);
            }

        };
        st.open();        

    }

    public void stop(BundleContext bc) throws Exception {
        bc.ungetService(bc.getServiceReference(SessionHandle.class.getName()));
        st.close();
    }

    private void debug(String msg) {
        System.out.println("JDBCTestBundleActivator: " + msg);
    }
}
```

When I try to compile the code with Netbeans this is the error that I get:

http://i39.tinypic.com/14xdw5c.png

How I can Fix this?

This is the complete source code:
http://www.2shared.com/file/bziA4e-n/SH_27.html

Best Wishes

Comment: Please show your complete error message text here, not in a link. Indicate by comment which line(s) of code throw the error.

Comment: would it help if i posted a screen shot without that little red line?

Comment: by the way, the down-vote isn't mine.

Comment: If you can show SessionHandle class, it will be easy to find the exact error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access the field `ds`, but the variable `sh` is of type `SessionHandle` (an interface) which does not have this field. The implementation `SessionHandleImpl` may have this field, but the compiler will only let you access methods and fields defined in the interface.

You could update the interface to specify a setter method for this field, by adding:

```
public void setDataSource(DataSource ds);
```

then implement that setter in the implementation class - something *like*:

```
    public void setDataSource(DataSource ds)
    {
        this.ds = ds;
    }
```

*but you'll need to look at the internals of SessionHandleImpl to do this correctly - I haven't looked and it might even have the setter method already!*

Then finally call `sh.setDataSource(ds)` rather than `sh.ds=ds`

**Update**: Alternatively you can declare `sh` as type SessionHandleImpl, so all its fields will be visible. You then can't easily change to another implementation - but since the implementation class is hardcoded here, that's not the end of the world:

```
SessionHandleImpl sh = new SessionHandleImpl();
```

Comment: Excuse me for my lack of knowledge. I'm still learning Java. Would you show me correct code.

Answer (score 4):

The error marker is simply indicating there's no accessible member `ds` in the `SessionHandle` class; beyond that, you haven't given us anything to go on. Maybe it's private, maybe it's called something different? You need to reexamine your assumption that such a field exists. The error message that goes with the marker might provide more detail.

Comment: Here is the code of SessionHandle: http://pastebin.com/QV5FdzSr   You can find the complete source code here http://www.2shared.com/file/bziA4e-n/SH_27.html     This is the error: http://pastebin.com/nxbY1EUY